# lightningchart.js Box Series 3D highlight a single box and get it's value

Tags: lightningchart

Working on a project using this example https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0907-3dBoxRounded.html
Is they an option to highlight on mouse hover a single box and get it's values?
Highlighting the whole box series isn't that usefull in my use case and splinting each box into a single Box Series 3D I suspect will tank the performance by a lot (and I do have a lot of boxes).

Comment: There's currently no features for solving which box is under mouse. Individual box coloring should be possible as a workaround to get individual highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Individual box will help me at least highlighting a box from a 2D preview chart with I do plan to add into this project anyway. So that will work for me.
Looking forward for having an option to get box under mouse information/event.